# Laravel: How can I get specific data from system() output and display in my blade file

Tags: php, laravel, server, laravel-blade, ping

I am trying to ping all of my servers using a batch file, because someone told me that it's the fastest way to ping multiple ip addresses.

```
//Home Controller
    $servers = Server::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);

    $batch_string=' set list=';

    foreach ($servers as $server)

      $batch_string.=$server->ip.' ';

      $batch_string.= "\n (for %%a in (%list%) do (
      ping -n 1 %%a
      ));";

      echo "<pre>";

      file_put_contents('batch.bat',$batch_string);

      system('cmd /c .\batch.bat', $output);
```

Now I want to check if the pings were successful or not and return an indicator if the server is online or not in my blade file. It only returns this.

[image]

Comment: Why are you using the system to do these things when there are `PHP` native functions that could handle it. Also, using system is very dangerous. All it takes is a rogue piece of text and your server is exposed

Comment: because using exec and fsock takes too much time to ping all of the ip addresses from the database, that's why i need to get only the necessary data from system() output

Comment: So compromise safety & security for speed?

Comment: is there any other way though? I think i could hide these details by manipulating the returned string by system() output

Comment: personally, I'd make a page where There's a button that had an ajax request to ping the servers with curl, and return the response next to the server if they responded or not

Comment: can you make a code snippet for it with laravel? please :(

Comment: Take a look at this: http://php.net/curl_multi_init it's native PHP, so you'd have to adapt it into a controller

Comment: i'm new to this curl in php, how can i ping these ip addresses and return the results